# defer destroyed in vue lifecycle hook

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my component I have a `mounted` hook that fetches some data as an async request:

```
mounted() {
  this.fetchData()
}
```

and on `beforeDestroy` I delete the data from the store:

```
beforeDestroy(){
  this.destroyDataInStore()
}
```

These work fine so long as the request in `mounted` resolves prior to the component begins its tear down.

Is there any way I can defer the `beforeDestroy` until *after* the promise has resolved in the mount?

Comment: So you need to actually defer the destroy itself, not the invocation of hook, right?

Answer (score 2):

You could store the promise:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            thePromise: null
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.thePromise = this.fetchData()
    },
    beforeDestroy () {
        this.thePromise.then(() => {
            this.destroyDataInStore()
        })
    }
}
```

But in order to be sure that everything works fine I would use the `created` hook instead of the `mounted` one:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            thePromise: null
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.thePromise = this.fetchData()
    },
    beforeDestroy () {
        this.thePromise.then(() => {
            this.destroyDataInStore()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Use empty promise `(Promise.resolve())` to avoid errors. But in general I'd rather use cancellables or even observables here; the problem is in fetchData side effects.

Comment: Where would you use that?

Comment: this would just defer the data being destroyed, not the actual tear down. this wouldn't solve the problem i'm having unfortunately

Comment: basically the next component being traversed to is relying on the store to be empty   on its mount

Comment: It would defer the data being destroyed only if your promise is not resolved when the component is destroyed. If the promise is already resolved, it would destroy the data directly.

Comment: Or you could add some sort of "lock" into your store to say which component is supposed to fill the store, in case the first promise resolves after the promise being resolved in the next component

Comment: `But in order to be sure that everything works fine I would use the created hook instead of the mounted one` Why? What does that change in regards to OP's problem?

Comment: I would say that if there is a mount error, the mounted hook would not be triggered. So `this.thePromise.then` would throw an error (because thePromise is null by default) in the beforeDestroy hook. Using created hook solves this problem